# Characterization of all golden triples

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Say a triple $(x, y, z) \in \mathbf{N}^3$ is *golden* if the following happens: first, $x$ and $y$ are distinct, and moreover$$\frac{x}{y} = z$$ and $$\frac{x_0 \cdots x_m}{y_0 \cdots y_n} = z$$ Here, $x_0, ..., x_m$ (and similarly $y_0, \dots, y_n$) are digits of the base-$10$ representation of $x$ (similarly of $y$). In other words $x = \sum_{i=0}^{m} 10^i x_{m - i}$.

For an example, consider $x = 64$, $y = 16$. Then with $z = 4$, one has $\frac{64}{16} = 4$, but similarly, $\frac{6\cdot 4}{1 \cdot 6} = 4$.

My general question is: do other such examples exist, and if so, what do they look like?

Comment: I think there are lots of examples, $(95,19,5), (995,199,5)$ just to mention two.  Indeed $(9^n5,19^n,5)$ always works.

Comment: @DrewBrady Trivially, $(x,x,1)$ will work for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yes, @lulu, good examples

Comment: @John Omielan. Of course, point well taken. Perhaps to make it more interesting we should exclude this case.

Comment: @DrewBrady I agree. In asking these sorts of general type questions, it's often helpful to explicitly exclude various trivial cases. You may wish to update your question text to state that $x \neq y$.

Comment: I just added the phraseology:"are distinct". Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Similarly, $(9^n8, 49^n, 2)$ always works.